# String matching between files Linux

Tags: file, grep, pattern-matching

I have two files that I want to compare. The first is tab separated, the second is comma separated and both begin with an ID. I want to match those IDs and do two things. First, I want to print out all of the ones that match between the two files. Then (if possible) I want to print to a separate file all of those that do not match. 
The files look like this:
(comma separated)

```
S-3DFSG,0,254654,3,e /// x, /// 5
S-8FGDG,6,464782,6,i /// n /// n /// e /// n, ///  /
S-4SKDH,0,445676,3,n /// e /// p, ///  /// F
```

(tab separated)

```
S-3DGSF DG  2   5   7   DF  2   2   4684648654
S-4GXBG DF  6   2   4   FD  7   1   2415244459
S-3DFST GA  0   8   4   CF  9   8   2
```

I tried

```
grep -F -wf file1 file2 > incommon.txt
```

For grep fixed pattern -only words that match from these files

But I got nothing output... 
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can improve this? I did think about regex but I am not terribly proficient in its use. I wouldn't mind using it though.

Comment: do you have python installed on the machine?

Comment: @ChaseTheSun I am not sure... I am not the only user on the machine. How would I check?

Comment: at a command prompt type 'python' or 'whereis python' or 'which python' or 'find / -name python'

Comment: @ChaseTheSun Yes I do.Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct 12 2012, 14:23:48) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

analyze.py:

```
import re

f = open('tab.txt', 'r')
data_tab = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('csv.txt', 'r')
data_csv = f.read()
f.close()

matches_tab = re.findall(r'^([^\t]+)', data_tab, re.M)
matches_csv = re.findall(r'^([^,]+)', data_csv, re.M)

common = set(matches_tab) & set(matches_csv)
not_common = set(matches_tab) ^ set(matches_csv)

f = open('common.txt', 'w')
for el in common:
    f.write(el)
    f.write('\n')
f.close()

f = open('not_common.txt', 'w')
for el in not_common:
    f.write(el)
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Save this in a file called *analyze.py* and run the script by using:

```
python analyze.py
```

Change tab.txt to your tabbed filename, csv.txt to your comma separated filename, and your lists should be dumped in the working directory. 
Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: This works perfectly. It has been a long while since I have used Python and because you seem SUPER proficient in it, I have to ask, do you have any preferred sources to reference/learn/touch up python?

Comment: I'm glad it works well. The python website was quite helpful, as was http://www.sthurlow.com/python/ . (I literally only started Python coding 7 days ago)

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to do it in the shell, for the "in common" you may  use:

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),.*/\1/' commed.txt > __ids.txt
grep -F -f __ids.txt $f tabbed.txt
rm -f __ids.txt
```

and for the "not in common":

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),.*/\1/' commed.txt > __ids.txt
grep -F -v -f __ids.txt $f tabbed.txt
sed 's/\([^\t]*\)\t.*/\1/' commed.txt > __ids.txt
grep -F -v -f __ids.txt $f tabbed.txt
rm -f __ids.txt
```

Where "commed.txt" is the file comma-separated and "tabbed.txt" is the file tab-separated.

This might fail if the ID may occur elsewhere in the second file! A more robust solution with "grep" is possible if the ID cannot be mistaken for a regexp (no `.`, `,`, `\`, `*`, etc).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post/ direct me to a post where a regexp solution can be found? As I mentioned in my post, I thought of using it but was unsure of how to go about it. I would like to learn though!